# using Regex to find a keyword in an exception string and send email based on that

Tags: python, logging

I have created a logging script within python that allows me to log errors that occur within scripts that have the log initialised. I have specific errors that I want to be able to catch and email out using the email functionality and then stop the script. Is this possible and if so how? I have tried everything I can think. My log code is as follows;

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

file_handler = logging.FileHandler('big_errors.log')
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

print_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
print_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
print_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

# added email functionality 
email_list = ["Example@gmail.com"]

mail_handler = logging.handlers.SMTPHandler(
    mailhost=('smtpmail1.mail-uk.loc', 25),
    fromaddr="Example@gmail.co.uk",
    toaddrs= email_list,
    subject='ErrorTEST'
)

mail_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.addHandler(mail_handler)
logger.addHandler(print_handler)
```

the specific line im looking to capture is

```
('08s01' [Database] communication link failure (-4) (SQLFETCH)')
```

my code has a try except block, how can i use a regular expression to find the keyword i am looking for and then call the log i have created to email the error?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a log Filter.

```
import re

def regex_filter(record):
    regex_matches_message = bool(re.search(r'your_regex_here', record.getMessage()))
    return regex_matches_message

mail_handler.addFilter(regex_filter)
```

Requires python at least 3.2, if you are on an older version you have to use a Filter object instead of a function. The `bool()` is not strictly needed but makes the code more explicit.

Comment: so what would it look like overall i have added that code in with my regex do i need to add a filter in the logger?

Comment: You can add it either to the handler or the logger. In your case you probably want it only on the handler, thus `mail_handler.addFilter(regex_filter)`. Whenever the filter returns false the log is discarded. [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#filter-objects)